# AngularJS ng-repeat first item always null

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

as mentioned in the topic, what is the problem when ever I use ng-repeat on a thing the first element is always null? I have tried several methods to get rid of this issue but doesn't seem to work.

All my ng-repeat data is stored in a JSON file and the JSON file will be passed to scope via a $http call like such:

```
        $http.get('index.php?r=exploreComment/WS_getExploreComments&topic_id=' + topic_id).success(function(data){
        $scope.comments = data;
        console.log('Comment Loaded');
```

Everything loaded properly just that the first item in the ng-repeat loop is always null..

```
GET http://localhost/viralenz/resource/_explore/%7B%7Bphoto.image%7D%7D 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://localhost/viralenz/resource/_explore/%7B%7Bimage.image%7D%7D 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://localhost/viralenz/resource/_users/%7B%7Bcomment.user_id%7D%7D/avatar/%7B%7Bcomment.avatar%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

I thought it was only an error for JSON data but then I tried on images, the same problem appears as well... I could not add images so I attached a link...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsFDX.png

What have I done wrong?

**///// Edited with more details ////**

This is how the ng-repeat looks like

```
<div class="exploreCommentBlock" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr style="width: 100%">

            <td style="width: 5%" rowspan="2" valign="top"><img
                src="<?php echo UrlMgmt::getUserResourceUrl()?>{{comment.user_id}}/avatar/{{comment.avatar}}"
                , style='height: 64px; width: 64px; border-radius: 5px;' /></td>



            <td style="width: 70%"><span class="author_name">{{comment.username}}</span>

--AND--SO--ON--
```

And this is the JSON data:

```
[{"comment_id":"92","user_id":"1","topic_id":"1","data":"lalalalalalaa","image_append":null,"rating":"1","datetime":"2014-08-19 13:03:58","username":"Kenny Yap","avatar":"14079353851"},
{"comment_id":"91","user_id":"1","topic_id":"1","data":"test blank post","image_append":null,"rating":"1","datetime":"2014-08-19 10:48:41","username":"Kenny Yap","avatar":"14079353851"},
{"comment_id":"28","user_id":"2","topic_id":"1","data":"test owner comment","image_append":null,"rating":"5","datetime":"2014-08-18 09:39:59","username":"Dummy User","avatar":"default_avatar.png"}]
```

Comment: How the data looks like, how the ng-repeat looks like?

Comment: @PSL I've added the ng-repeat and JSON data sample.. Thx

Comment: Which field is shown as null? Are you not showing the relevant section in the html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `img src="{{stuff}}"` inside your ng-repeat (or on your page in general), you'll get errors when the page first loads and {{stuff}} comes up as undefined. The trick is to use `img ng-src="{{stuff}}"` instead, which properly handles when the variable isn't defined.

Comment: so what you suggest is try on ng-src instead of src? Okay thanks... I'll have a try now and let you know about it...

Comment: I have found my problem and solves it... Firstly its the ng-src issue which mitigates half of my error, and I realized somehow when I decode the json file at the client side, a mysterious "," appears at the very front array which causes a NULL in the image display... Thanks for your help as well @pfooti

Answer (score 0):

A further investigation of your code indicates that there's something else going on here, probably not the ng-src thing I linked above.

Specifically, you are doing a  inside the ng-repeat to source the image. I'd look there to see where the problem is, and realistically if you're already loading the user's profile information, you should probably just load the image data via angular rather than injecting it in via php.